# GDB, how do I find the location of variables

Tags: c, gdb

I'm working with gdb to debug a c-executable.

I have this simple file

```
int main() {
    char *secret = "secret";

    char *buf = "hey";
    
    write(1, buf, 250);
}
```

Which I then run with gdb.
I would then like to see the variable `secret` on the stack.
This however I cannot figure out how to do, I tried:

```
$ info locals
No symbol table info available.
```

With no effect.
So how does one find the location of a variable?

Answer (score 0):

In order for GDB to know the location of local variables, you must compile your source(s) with `-g` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a result if you compile with the `-g` flag and set a breakpoint somewhere in `main`. If you haven't run the program yet, or let it complete, you won't see the local variables.

For example:

```
(gdb) b 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1004010a3: file sec.c, line 6.
(gdb) r
[.....]
Thread 1 "sec" hit Breakpoint 1, main () at sec.c:6
6           write(1, buf, 250);
(gdb) info locals
secret = 0x100403000 "secret"
buf = 0x100403007 "hey"
```

Alternatively, you can just print a variable to see the address:

```
(gdb) print secret
$1 = 0x100403000 "secret"
```

For something like an `int` you would have to use `print &x` to see the address as `print x` will just show the value.

Answer (score 0):

`info variables YOUR_VARIABLE` should output the source location of a variable:

For example:

```
(gdb) info variables quote_quoting_options
All variables matching regular expression "quote_quoting_options":

File lib/quotearg.c:
1044:   struct quoting_options quote_quoting_options;
```